# Is it possible to use resttemplate to upload file in azure blob storage - Java

Tags: java, azure-blob-storage, spring-resttemplate

Is there a way to upload files to Azure blob storage using rest template in Java - Spring framework ? I see all examples using SDK and it was successful but we are told not to use SDK - Java.
I know question is 10,000 feet high, but any pointers/direction will help a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No idea why not to use SDK, Also no idea who might be told you.

Anyway, Yes you can use RestTemplate or even better [webClient](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.x/reference/html/boot-features-webclient.html).

All you have to do is to map the request sent with the SDK to the cloud.

You have to add header authentication manually. serialize the file I suppose.

And it's a lot of work when you do have a supported SDK for client.

For example , here is a simple request sent with WebClient for Redmine server

```
String url = "http://localhost:3001/projects.json"; //Redmine local server
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
JSONObject object = new JSONObject();   //Json object that will need to be sent to redmine
object.put("name", "dummyName");        // Should look like this
object.put("identifier", "dummyId");    // {"project":{"identifier":"dummyId","name":"dummyName"}}
JSONObject body = new JSONObject();     
body.put("project", object);            
String plainCreds = "user:bitnami1"; // default basic auth encoding
byte[] plainCredsBytes = plainCreds.getBytes();
byte[] base64CredsBytes = Base64.encodeBase64(plainCredsBytes);
String base64Creds = new String(base64CredsBytes);
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.add("Authorization", "Basic " + base64Creds); 
headers.add("Content-Type", "application/json");
RequestEntity<JSONObject> requestEntity = RequestEntity
                .post(new URI(url))
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .headers(headers)
                .body(body);
ResponseEntity<String> r = restTemplate.exchange(requestEntity, String.class);
```

And this is who the same example will look like using RestTemplate

```
String url = "http://localhost:3001/projects.json"; //Redmine local server
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
JSONObject object = new JSONObject();   //Json object that will need to be sent to redmine
object.put("name", "dummyName");        // Should look like this
object.put("identifier", "dummyId");    // {"project":{"identifier":"dummyId","name":"dummyName"}}
JSONObject body = new JSONObject();     
body.put("project", object);            
String plainCreds = "user:bitnami1"; // default basic auth encoding
byte[] plainCredsBytes = plainCreds.getBytes();
byte[] base64CredsBytes = Base64.encodeBase64(plainCredsBytes);
String base64Creds = new String(base64CredsBytes);
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.add("Authorization", "Basic " + base64Creds); 
headers.add("Content-Type", "application/json");
HttpEntity<Object> entity = new HttpEntity<Object>(body, headers);
ResponseEntity<String> result = restTemplate.exchange("http://localhost:3001/projects.json",
                HttpMethod.POST,
                entity,
                String.class);
```

Both of these, Were only possible because am trying to match this curl request

```
curl --location --request POST 'localhost:3001/projects.json' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic dXNlcjpiaXRuYW1pMQ==' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{"project":{"identifier":"dummyId","name":"dummyName"}}'
```

So once You know what the request looks like, You can use RestTemplate or WebClient, or any other similar class to build up your request.